# How do I remove # sign from hash data? jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need value of hash from url...

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

So how do I get rid of `#` sign?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between slice() and substr() in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546284/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-and-substr-in-javascript)

Comment: @alex23 relax. I still cannot approve answer, 1 min remaining.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As easy as that.

```
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1)
```

There are also these two which return the exact same:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1)
var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1)
```

`String.slice()` was added to the spec a little later, although that's propably unimportant.

Using replace as mentioned below is an option, too.

None of those options throw an error or warning if the `window.location.hash` string is empty, so it really depends on your preferences what to use.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this -

```
hash = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
```

Comment: I think `hash.replace('#','')` is more safe than `slice(1)`

Comment: In that case you probably want to use `hash.replace(/^#/, '')` so you exclusively remove a leading `#`, not ones that are part of the hash.

Answer (score 1):

Just cut out the first char:

```
 var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
 var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
```

Note that it doesn't produce an error if there is no hash in the location, it just returns `""`.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href.substr(0, window.location.href.indexOf('#'))` will do the trick