# Why two different methods slice() & substring()?

Tags: javascript, substring, slice, substr

```
var name="nameSomnath";//remove name
```

I can do with `slice()`

```
var result = name.slice( 4 );
```

Same can be done with `substring()`

```
var result = name.substring( 4 );
```

So what makes them different. 
I have seen the link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546284/what-is-the-difference-between-slice-and-substr-in-javascript) which elaborates the difference .But we can do the same thing by using any one method ie `slice()` or `substring()`.So why there was need to have two methods.

Comment: You can refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243824/what-is-the-difference-between-string-slice-and-string-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though it looks superficially like `slice` and `substring` do the same thing, the big difference is in how they handle negative arguments.

When JavaScript was first created in Netscape 2.0, there was just a `substring` method. If either of its arguments are negative, they are treated as 0.

When JavaScript 1.2 was introduced with Netscape 4.0, they wanted to add the behavior of allowing negative indexes to mean distances from the end of the string. They couldn't change `substring` to have this new behavior because it would break backward compatibility with scripts that expected negative indexes to be treated as 0, so they had to create a new function to support the added feature. This function was called `slice`, and was implemented on `Array` as well as `String`.

Another, smaller difference is that with `substring` the order of the arguments doesn't matter, so `substring(1, 4)` is the same as `substring(4, 1)`. With `slice`, order does matter, so `slice(4, 1)` will just yield an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

One item that makes them different is the second parameter that you have omitted

- `slice`: the second parameter is the end index (exclusive) of the range to take.
- `substr`: the second parameter is the length of the string to take from the index specified with the first parameter

Can you completely replicate the behavior of one method with the other on `string` instances?  Yes.  Why they chose to include both is probably lost to history.  My guess though would be familiarity.  I bet there are very few frameworks out there which have `slice` for `strings` but plenty that have `substr`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**:
Oooops - I was wrong - there IS a slice method for strings too! I will delete my post again - sorry for not researching properly!!! Or, well , may be not delete it, but leave this correction in it at least. ;-)

You are looking at two methods of different classes. `substr` can only be applied on `String`-objects while `slice` belongs to `Array`-objects. They might seem similar to yo, yet internally they work in different ways since the data they handle is different.

BTW, this is *not* a jQuery but a plain JavaScript question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In `slice` the arguments are the first index and last index. In `substr`, the arguments are first index and length.

Comment: This wasn't the question. The question was about slice and substring.

Answer (score 0):

slice() and substring() do the same thing with some common behaviors, but there are some distinctions in the handling negative arguments

```
Syntax: string.slice(start, stop);
Syntax: string.substring(start, stop);
```

Common behaviors:

1. If start equals stop: returns an empty string
2. If the stop is omitted: extracts characters to the ethe nd of the string
3. If either argument is greater than the string's length, the string's
   length will be used instead.

Distinctions of [substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

1. If start > stop, then substring will swap those 2 arguments.
2. If either argument is negative or is NaN, it is treated as if it
   were 0.

Distinctions of [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

1. If start > stop, slice() will return the empty string. ("")
2. If the start is negative: sets char from the end of the string, exactly
   like substr() in Firefox. This behavior is observed in both Firefox
   and IE.
3. If the stop is negative: sets stop to: string.length – Math.abs(stop)
   (original value), except bounded at 0 (thus, Math.max(0,
   string.length + stop)) as covered in the [ECMA specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-string.prototype.slice).

Source: [Javascript: substr() v.s. substring()](https://rapd.wordpress.com/2007/07/12/javascript-substr-vs-substring)

Answer (score -1):

### slice

> .slice(start, end)

*Does not include, the given **end index** element*

---

### substr

> .substr(start,*length*)

*Extracts from **start** position up to the **no. of chars.** specified*

---

### substring

> .substring(start, end)

*extracts the characters **between** the two specified indices*

---

Comment: For More info about `substr` and `substring` http://stackoverflow.com/a/22439570/2557900

Comment: slice() does **not** return an array: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp

Comment: Charles,  that was from my confusion with the array one, , should've updated long before. Thanks for pointing it out!